# How to get the name of the top most (entry) script in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, introspection

I have a utility module in Python that needs to know the name of the application that it is being used in.   Effectively this means the name of the top-level python script that was invoked to start the application (i.e. the one where __name=="__main__" would be true).  __name__ gives me the name of the current python file, but how do I get the name of the top-most one in the call chain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having switch my Google query to "how to to find the *process* name from python" vs how to find the "top level script name", I found [this overly thorough treatment of the topic](http://doughellmann.com/2012/04/determining-the-name-of-a-process-from-python-2.html).  The summary of which is the following:

```
import __main__
import os

appName = os.path.basename(__main__.__file__).strip(".py")
```

Comment: The strip part isn't quite right in some cases: `"pretend_example_silly.py".strip(".py")` gives `"retend_example_sill"`. `os.path.basename(__main__.__file__).split(".")[0]`might be a better heuristic

Comment: `Python version 3.9 does not have module __main__`
How do we do this in Python 3.9?

Comment: doesn't work. it seems like it produces the main script's file name at time of compilation. So if two programs use the same import, you can get the wrong (static) result.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module for this. For example:

**a.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import b
```

**b.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import inspect

print inspect.stack()[-1][1]
```

Running `python b.py` prints `b.py`. Running `python a.py` prints `a.py`.

However, I'd like to second the suggestion of `sys.argv[0]` as a more sensible and idiomatic suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.9 (as noted in the comments) there's no `__main__` **identifier**. However, the **name** of that module is still `'__main__'` (with quotes, since it's a string). Else the usual `__name__=='__main__'` idiom wouldn't work.

Hence, the solution is easy: Just use `sys.modules['__main__'].__file__` instead of `__main__.__file__`.